# JavaScript Event Delegation code organization

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I am binding a single click event to a large container using jQuery (event delegation).

I have many different items within that container that are clickable.

The problem I am dealing with is that if I have 20 clickable items, I need to do a if else block x 20 in the container on click handler.  Is there a way to make this cleaner?  E.g.:

```
attachClickEvent:function(){
    $(".container").click($.proxy(this.handleOnClick,this));
},
handleOnClick:function(event){
     var $target = $(event.target);
     if($target.closest(".widget1").length >0){
         //handle widget 1 interaction
     }else if($target.closest(".widget2").length >0){
         //handle widget 2 interaction
     }else if($target.closest(".widget3").length >0){
         //handle widget 3 interaction
     }else if($target.closest(".widget4").length >0){
         //handle widget 4 interaction
     }else if($target.closest(".widget5").length >0){
         //handle widget 5 interaction
     }
}
```

etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing that comes to mind is using a loop:

```
var handlers = {
  "widget1": function(event, candidate){},
  "widget2": function(event, candidate){}
}

$.each(handlers, function(cssClass,handler){
  var sel = '.'+cssClass;
  var candidate = target.closest(sel);
  if(candidate.length > 0) {
    handler(event, candidate);
    break;
  }
});
```

Comment: Your use of target implies you're running this loop inside the click handler. This is not good because you'll have to run $(target).closest() potentially 20+ times to find the matching property.  You're also using the `class` keyword which will barf in webkit.

Comment: @typeof: it is running inside the click handler... he is delegating to the parent element containing a set of 20 items that each have specific handler actions. There fore he needs to loop through all selectors until he gets a match then invoke the associated handler function. `target.closest(sel)` is his test... there for it must be invoked in each iteration until matched - then when match break out of the loop. Changed the variable name.. though this wanst meant to be working code... just a rough example

Comment: The loop is not necessary and shouldn't be used.

Comment: @typeof: then how would you implement? I agree there is probably a better way to test or even perhaps figure you which handler to invoke with a single test selector, but he hasnt shown enough of his code to determine what that would so insted i did specifically what he asked - give an alternative to using a 20 condition if/else

Answer (score 2):

**Create Object With Functions**

A little late to the game with this, but you should consider organizing your code like this.

If you have 20 unique actions for your widgets, you're going to all that code.  Try to reuse common code by creating functions.  Make a structure like this:

```
var actions = {
    'widget1' : function(event) {
        // handle widget 1 interaction
    },
    'widget2' : function(event) {
        // handle widget 2 interaction
    },
    'widget3' : function(event) {
        // handle widget 3 interaction
    },
    call : function(event) {
        var prefix = "widget",
            widget = $(event.target).closest('[class^="'+prefix+'"]'),
            classN;
        if(widget.length) {
            classN = widget.attr('class').replace(new RegExp('.*('+prefix+'\\d*).*$'), '$1');
            if(classN in this) {
                this[classN](event);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**Simplified Execution**

Then, from your click handler, simply call the function like this:

```
handleOnClick : function(event) {
    actions.call(event)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery offers this functionality out of the box:

```
$('.container').on('click', '.widget1', function() {
    // handle widget 1 interaction
});

$('.container').on('click', '.widget2', function() {
    // handle widget 2 interaction
});
```

I recently wrote a library to extract that if you are not using jQuery.  It's called gator.  You can see examples/documentation at:
http://craig.is/riding/gators

You can do something like

```
Gator(container_element).on('click', '.widget1', function() {
    // handle widget 1 interaction
});

Gator(container_element).on('click', '.widget2', function() {
    // handle widget 2 interaction
});
```

Both jQuery and Gator only bind a single click event to the container element and handle dispatching the events internally.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="container">
 <div id="cont1"></div>
 <div id="cont2"></div>
 <div id="cont3"></div>
 <div id="cont4"></div>
 <div id="cont5"></div>
 <div id="cont6"></div>
.
.
.

</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".container").find("div").click(function(){
id = $(this).attr("id");
if(id=="cont1"){
...
}
else if(id=="cont2"){
..
}
..
else{
..
}
});
```

Comment: That's no longer event delegation, you are binding an event to every div.  Also, you are stil doing an if/else x number of divs.

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps something you are looking for.  There a bunch of different ways to do this.

```
<div id="widgetcontainer">
    <div id="widget1">A</div>
    <div id="widget2">B</div>
    <div id="widget3">C</div>
    <div id="widget4">D</div>
    <div id="widget5">E</div>  
</div>
```

Here is the JS

```
function someAction() {
    alert("Hey");
}


$(function() {
    var wc = $("#widgetcontainer div");
    for (var i = 0; i < wc.length; i++) {
        $(wc[i]).click(function() {
            someAction();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This is still not event delegation.  Event delegation is binding one single event to the parent and listening to the events the bubble up from clicks on child nodes.  Here you are binding a click event to every div.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `delegate`?

```
$(".container").
    delegate(".widget1", "click", widget_1_handler).
    delegate(".widget2", "click", widget_2_handler)
;
```